# When I created the spring MVC project with STS, how can modify the default XML content

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

I use the STS to creat Spring MVC project, STS version is 3.7.3.RELEASE.
the default spring xml configuration file is :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="test.dmh.hw" />

</beans:beans>
```

but when I configure my own HandlerInterceptorAdapter, I found the config file is not meeting my requirement. because the head is :
beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
So I have to edit the file like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="com.shanshan.bo" />

    <!-- 配置拦截器 -->
    <mvc:interceptors>
        <!-- 多个拦截器，按顺序执行 -->
        <mvc:interceptor>
            <mvc:mapping path="/**"/> <!-- 表示拦截所有的url包括子url路径 -->
            <bean class="com.shanshan.bo.interceptor.LoginHandlerInterceptor"/>
        </mvc:interceptor>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

change the head : beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

Now I want the file format is this when I creat the project, so I don't have to change it anymore.
How can I edit the springmvc.xml file content ?

Comment: Why can't you directly edit the file?

Comment: I want it creat the right xml file what  I want, then I do not to edit the file by myself.

Comment: You don't need to edit it.... The fact that you want the `mvc` prefix indicates to me you have a weak understanding of xml namespaces. In the first the `mvc` namespace is the root namespace so instead of `mvc:intereptors` you can write `interceptors` the modified version has the `beans` namespace as the root and hence you need to prefix all the other (non beans related things) with the namespace prefix.

Comment: Which version of STS are you using?

Comment: The STS version is 3.7.3.RELEASE,I hava said in the beginning of the question. And...in fact, I use SpringMVC for just two months. But how can I  change the namespaces from mvc to beans ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Tool Suite has `Spring Config Editor`, which you can use to edit namespaces.

To open file with `Spring Config Editor`, right click on the file and select `Open With>Spring Config Editor`. Check image below

[image]

Now you can edit the namespaces using the `Namespaces` tab at the bottom of this editor. 
[image]

Following is a sample Namespaces tab

[image]

Comment: I think your solution is add or remove the namespaves by a simple way, but not change the namespaces. This can not solve my problem.

Comment: What do you mean by changing the namespace?

Comment: Look at the reply above of M. Deinum . I think I see what he means, but I don't know what to do

Comment: He is saying that any XML file has a single root `namespace`, in your case it's `beans`. namespace is like a package in Java. Inside a package you don't need to qualify components from the same package, but if you want to use components from other packages you do need to qualify them. Same goes for XML namespaces. components in default name space don't need to be qualified as `beans:beans`. First `beans` is the namespace shorthand, second `beans` is the component defined in it. If you want to use components from `mvc` namespace in the same file, you'll have to qualify them with `mvc:`

Comment: Thank you! I think I see what you mean. If I use mvc:interceptor in beans:beans xml file, I can write it directly interceptor, meanwhile, I should write beans:bean  instead of bean. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, I missed it the first time, your default namespace is `mvc`. Default namespace is the one which doesn't have anything after it's `xmlns` attribute, so `xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"` is default where as `xmlns:xsi=...` namesace components would have to be referred as `xsi:some-component` or `xmlns:beans=...`  components would have to be referred as `beans:some-component`